# Do i need a patent attorney for filing a patent when the invention is very simple?

Tags: pct, patent-services

I read everywhere that it is recommended to let a patent attorney create the patent description and file it for you. But patent attorney's are also very expensive. It would set me back about 8000 euro's in total.

My invention is very simple and has only 2 ingredients, the process in which it is made is also very simple and can be described in just a few lines of text. Do I need a patent attorney for filing a patent for such an invention?

I am looking to file a PCT application for my invention first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a retired U.S. patent agent but with no experience in chemical patents which are a specialized sub-field in patent practice.

Some people make a serious avocation of pursuing their own patents and can be successful but it is a big time commitment and steep learning curve that, if a good idea at all, would be for a serial inventor.

Since you denominated your possible cost in Euros I assume you are not in the US. Nonetheless you can file a provisional application in the US for very little cost and low formality requirements (in contrast to a PCT application). You might then rely, for a year, on the Paris Convention to give you the ability to disclose the invention to potential investors and business partners without breaking novelty.

Such a simple invention may already be known and a good starting place is a professional search that might cost a few hundred dollars. It could turn out that the substance is not new but your intended use is new. That would dictate a different approach to drafting a specification and claim set.

If either of the two ingredients is part of a family of substances with similar properties (almost always the case) your claims need to be broad enough to encompass those or competitors have an easy work-around.

To be novel means, at least, never written about at the day you file in a publicly available document in any language at any time.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a lawyer, but I am the inventor of quite a few patents. In the US, at least, one can file a patent application without the help of a lawyer. I suspect the same is true for a PCT.  That said, in my opinion, it is a bad idea to do so. A patent application is a legal document. Patent attorneys draft applications with specific legal requirements and precedents in mind. Claims especially needed to be worded precisely to get effective protection of the invention. During the prosecution of the application, there are processes that are likely to trip you up without the support of a lawyer. Getting a rejection is very likely if not certain. Navigating the process without a lawyer is likely to either result in not achieving a patent or obtaining a narrow and ineffective patent.

The thing to remember is the patent is a tool for making money from your invention. It protects you from someone copying your invention. If you don't expect to make sufficient income to cover the cost of obtaining a patent, there is no point to pursuing one.

Now if your invention is really simple, it may well be easier and thus cheaper for an attorney to draft the application. However, if the invention is very simple, it well may be considered either not novel or obvious by the patent examiner. A patent attorney will have drafted the application with this in mind. Some searching yielded the following sites which may help provide low cost legal services to defray some of the costs.

https://ficpi.org/ip-news/new-euipo-pro-bono-programme

https://euipo.europa.eu/ohimportal/en/online-services/sme-fund

https://www.wipo.int/iap/en/